# VoiceOver not reading menu item properly on first focus within dropdown menu

Tags: html, accessibility, voiceover, screen-readers, keyboard-navigation

I can't figure out why VoiceOver isn't reading my dropdown menu properly (the dropdown menu is based on the [WAI ARIA menu button pattern](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/menu-button/examples/menu-button-actions/)). It reads the menu button as expected, and individual items when navigating the menu - **but not when the menu opens up, and focuses on the first item**.

When the menu first opens and focuses on the first item - I expect something along the lines of "Apple, menu item, menu 4 items".

However, it reads: **"Apple, menu item, menu Fruitsand 3 more items 4 items"**.

Which is obviously clunky. And it actually reads it without the space between "Fruits" and "and", that was not a typo on my part.

What am I doing wrong with the semantics or aria-attributes here? I've also tried removing the aria-labelledby on the menu itself, incase that caused some repitition.

```html
<button
  id="trigger"
  aria-expanded="false"
  aria-haspopup="menu"
  aria-controls="list"
  type="button"
  >
  Fruits
</button>

<div
  id="list"
  role="menu"
  aria-orientation="vertical"
  aria-labelledby="trigger"
  tabindex="-1"
  >
  <div id="0" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Apple</div>
  <div id="1" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Banana</div>
  <div id="2" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Citrus</div>
  <div id="3" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Orange</div>
</div>
```

*ps. I'm using JS to deal with the navigation, but only sharing the HTML as this should be an issue in the HTML structure.*

Answer (score 0):

Even if you use aria roles etc., I would still use the common (descriptive) HTML5 tags for the menu: `<nav>`, and within that `<ul>` and `<li>`s with `<a>` tags, not  simply divs.

Comment: Sorry, my post didn't specify enough, it is a dropdown menu based on the menu button pattern, not a navigational menu.